# Why does my injected script code in WordPress site head appear to be outside the tag when viewing page source in browser?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I use the `wp_head` hook to inject some Google Tag code into the head of my WordPress site. However, when I view the page source in Chrome, the code appears to be misplaced above the `<head>` tag outside it in the top of the document. Why does it appear like this? Is the code misplaced by php code or does it just appear wrong in the page source view in Chrome?

php plugin code adding the Google Tag code to the:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: ... Add Google Tags
 * Plugin URI: http://www.mywebsite.com/my-first-plugin
 * Description: Adds the google tags
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: ...
 * Author URI: ...
 */

function add_code_to_header() {
?>
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-W4R4KNK');</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_code_to_header');

function add_code_on_body_open()
{
?>

    <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=..." height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>

<?php
}
add_action('wp_body_open', 'add_code_on_body_open');
```

How it looks when I view the page source:
[image]

I might misunderstand how the page source view works or how the php code generates the html.

Thanks!

Comment: use something like this plugin instead of writing php code https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/

Comment: Maybe I should. But I tried one of those plugins, specifically https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-footer/ and the script appeared placed outside the <head> tag there too.

Comment: I will try the plugin you linked if this doesn't get solved with my own code.

Comment: Where your placed the code `head ,body or footer` .. I have inspected your code that analytic code place under body tag  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sQgc.png

Comment: if still not working. i would suggest to use GA plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/ga-google-analytics/

Comment: It does not appear to be just this single script element that is misplaced though, in your screenshot there’s _lots_ of link and script elements, that appear not only before the `<head>` tat, but even before the doctype declaration. So something must be _seriously_ wrong with your setup or your template.

Answer (score 0):

**Use wp_add_inline_script hook to add script in head tag.**

wp_add_inline_script() - without dependency Support from WP:5.0

**PHP code**

```
$my_scripts = "(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-W4R4KNK');";

wp_register_script( 'my-handle', '' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-handle' );
wp_add_inline_script( 'my-handle', $my_scripts );
```